# Using jQuery + php to include a file with ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a list of links which when clicked opens a link's corresponding DIV. These div's are hidden by default using both jquery .hide() and css display:none.

These divs all contain a php include to a file with a jquery product zoomer in, and because of the way I've made it, only the first one works and the div's below in the source order fail to work (they are included, but the jquery doesnt work) as I'm assuming it conflicts.

I'd love to be able to fix this apparant conflict, but haven't a clue what the issue may be, and as the site is "secret" I can't show the source here without giving away what it is.

So, i was thinking - instead of including these files via php, have them load in when the link is clicked, so only one of these includes is in the page at any one time!

Is this possible using jquery and some php?

---  edit ---

On further investigation - thanks to some of your comments below, it looks like jQuery's .load() looks suitable, but won't work for me. Here is my jQuery:

`

```
    $('.urbaneCarousel li.dowrImg').click(function(){
        $('ul.urbaneCarousel').hide();
        $('.dowrDiv, .dowrDiv div').show();
        $('.dowrDiv .insert').load('path/to/dowr.php');
        return false;
    });
```

`

Any advice? I'm 100% certain the path/to/ part is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have some conflicts between those php files. it shouldn't be an issue to include different php's into your hidden divs at all. In any case, couple ways you can do this:

1. Include all your content via php upfront and simply show the divs on the browser (sounds like what you're doing)

> < div id='mydiv1' style='display:none'>
>   < ?php include('myfile1'); ?>
>   < /div>
>
> < div id='mydiv2' style='display:none'>
>   < ?php include('myfile2'); ?>
>   < /div>

etc.
Then, on some click event, you would do $("#div1").show(), etc.

or

2) simply create your divs empty and bind click events to the .load or .get calls for specific divs

so let's say you have two buttons btn1 and btn2 for those divs.

```
$('#btn1').bind('click', function() {
    $("#div1").get('myfile1');
$("#div1").show();
});
```

The only problem with the second solution that it will go to the server to fetch data every time button is clicked.

**UPDATE**

try specifying full path in your .load or .get just to be safe. That might be giving you problems too. Here's a quick example (I am using codeIgniter, thus base_url() reference)

```
     $('#btn_trigger').live('click', function(){ 
            $("#dowrInsert").load("<?php echo base_url();?>auth/index"); 
    });

<input type='button' value='Trigger' id='btn_trigger'/>
<div id="dowrInsert">
    My text
</div>
```

This works fine

Comment: Thanks Alexey, I think that option 2 is better for me at this stage. I tried it using .load(), here is my code:

`  $('.urbaneCarousel li.dowrImg').click(function(){
   $('ul.urbaneCarousel').hide();
   $('.dowrDiv, .dowrDiv div').show();
   $('.hideTitle').hide();
   $('.showHide').hide();
   $('.dowrDiv .insert').load('product-zoomer/dowr.php');
   return false;
  });
'

For some reason, this doesn't work?

Comment: @tjcss, make sure you have full path in your load(). 'product-zoomer/dowr.php' will not work. It needs to be http://yourserver/yourpath/yourfile.ext. Also what is $('.dowrDiv .insert')? Looks like you are referencing a class. You better off referencing that by id (#) particularly if it's a specific div you're loading

Comment: I've changed it to an id, but it still doesn't seem to work. Also, relative or absolute urls make no difference either (the path is correct both times).

Very strange, do I need to do anything to the target div? All I've got is

<div id="dowrInsert"></div>

and then

 $('.urbaneCarousel li.dowrImg').click(function(){
  $('ul.urbaneCarousel').hide();
  $('#dowrInsert').load('http://www.../dowr.php');
  return false;
 });

Comment: you're right about relative/absolute. I wanted to make sure you're definitely pointing the right file. Have you checked 1) that click definitely gets triggered? Put alert('hi'); right at the beginning of click function. 2) that your dowrInsert is visible. Put some default text in it to see. also do $("#dowrInsert").show() inside 3) that you're definitely pointing to the right file. Change .load to get www.yahoo.com to see if that works

Comment: Right; the alert works, and my default content shows, but I can't get http://www.google.com or www.google.com to work.

Comment: @tjcss, right. The reason .get and .load don't get google.com is because of ajax same origin policy issues. My bad for mentioning that. Good thing is that all your code gets executed. I believe the issue is your file path. Make sure you specify FULL path to load and that will solve your issues. I will update my answer above with a snippet of code I just ran so you can see

Comment: I've tried my code using bbc.co.uk and also various paths, such as /var/www/vhosts/myurl.com/http. Have also tried .get() as well.

I should mention that I'm using wordpress, not sure if that is anything to be concerned about though?

Comment: Here is another snippet I just tried:


` $('.urbaneCarousel li.dowrImg').live('click',function(){
  $('ul.urbaneCarousel').hide();
  $('#dowrInsert').load("<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/themes/TimberWindows/product-zoomer/dowr.php");
  alert('hi');
  return false;
 });
`

Comment: @tjcss, bbc.co.uk is the same as google.com. Unless your wordpress site sits on bbc.co.uk, nothing will get loaded. Did you try full http path to your own server? Put a "Hello world" type file in your root and try .load("http://yourserver/helloworld.html")

Answer (score 0):

JQuery `.load` http://api.jquery.com/load/ | I guess you have to try to play with `.load` =)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to resolve the conflict which was leading to me needing to use the .load() method.

I'm sure there was something within my wordpress theme which was causing this to mess up, so thanks to all those who helped me looking for ways round this, but I managed to accidentally fix my initial conflict in any case, so no longer need the .load() method as a workaround.